# call external common function in jquery ui modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jQuery UI modal calling an external JSP. In the JSP I have HTML and jQuery code also. When opening the modal, a search screen appears and the search button should do a count of the characters in the textboxes when clicked.

Except it does not find the input boxes loaded by the modal, it finds the parent window's elements instead (also a search screen).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{  
    console.log('ready!');
    // Just some test code
    $("input[type='text']").each(function()
    {
        console.log("textbox: " + $(this).attr("id"));
    });
});

function countSearchChars()
{
    var count = 0;

    $("input[type='text'][name^='SEARCH_' i]").each(function()
    {
        alert($(this).attr("id") + " val count: " + $(this).val().length);
        count += $(this).val().length;
    });
    return count;
}
```

The parent JSP call -

```
$("body").append("<div id='modalCustomerServiceWindow'></div>");
$("#modalCustomerServiceWindow").dialog(
{ 
    autoOpen: false, draggable: true, 
    resizable: true, height: heightScreen, width: widthScreen, 
    modal: true, title: "Customer Service Notes",
    closeOnEscape: true,
    open: function(event, ui)
    {
        $(this).load(url);
    }
});
$("#modalCustomerServiceWindow").dialog("open");
```

Returns -

textbox: SEARCH_name_last
textbox: SEARCH_name_first
textbox: SEARCH_comp_1
textbox: SEARCH_internet_address
textbox: SEARCH_reg_uid
textbox: SEARCH_show_code
textbox: SEARCH_mail_type_code
textbox: SEARCH_org_id
textbox: SEARCH_link_reg_uid

Doesn't find any of these -

```
<input type="textbox" class="search-field comment" name="search_comments" 
            id="search_comments" size="90">
<input type="textbox" class="search-field" name="search_add_date" 
            id="search_add_date" size="15"></TH>
<input type="textbox" class="search-field" name="search_add_userid" 
            id="search_add_userid" size="9">
```

I put the count characters method in a global js file and moved it into the JSP file and the same result occurs. I moved the script tags before the body tag, but nothing different changed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the error. This code has been around since 2000.

```
<input type="textbox">
```

I guess IE has no problem with displaying this but jQuery obviously cannot find it.